# Select option become blank when Select2 is applied

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I currently have this input element being output to my browser:

```
<select name="data[Repository][owner_id]" class="owners" style="width: 100%" id="RepositoryOwnerId">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">value here</option>
</select>
```

When I add the jQuery code to enable Select2, it will remove the content of that option, I see nothing in the box. The value of the option is blank when I use Inspect Element in Firefox too.

```
$('#RepositoryOwnerId').selectize({
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'name',
    searchField: 'name',
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    options: [],
    create: false,
    render: {
        option: function(item, escape) {
            return '<div>'+ escape(item.name) + '</div>';
        }
    },
    load: function(query, callback) {

        if (!query.length) return callback();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/file/to/remote/<?php echo $id?>',
            type: 'GET',
            delay: 250,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                q: query
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                //alert(error);
                callback();
            },
            success: function(res) {
                callback(res.users);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Looking at the code of the following page:
https://select2.github.io/examples.html

I decided to initialized a variable as such:

```
echo "<script>var owners = [{ 'id': '12345', 'name': 'Name Here'}]</script>";
```

Then, in load, if the query length is 0, then return owners in the callback:

```
if (!query.length) return callback(owners);
```

That doesn't work either. If I add an alert in there, it doesn't get fired on page load.

Comment: Are you sure `options` should be an empty array `[]`?

Comment: @rac I removed options entirely and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `options: []`. You can't pass in an empty array, so just remove the reference.